# Как написать логику контроллеров Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

с недавнего времени начал писать пет проект на Asp.net mvc.
Создал модели(анемичные), написал слой для доступа к бд, и после этого остановился на вопросе а как собственно написать логику работы контроллеров. Натыкался на статьи что можно в контроллерах через репозиторий ходить в бд и тянуть информацию, но так же пишут что такой подход уже устарел и ни кто не делает так, а как тогда?. Натыкался на комментарии что нужно писать в CQRS стиле, но что это и как с этим работать новичку?
Посоветуйте пожалуйста где найти актуальную информацию как строить логику работы в контроллерах что бы было понятно новичку.

Comment: Обычно делают какой-то сервис который регистрируют в di контейнере, а потом в какой-то контроллер инжектят этот сервис. Для контроллера настраивают роут какой-нибудь. В методе контроллера вызывают конкретный метод сервиса. Обычно на репозитории БД накладывают еще один слой доступа чтобы можно было инкапсулировать часть логики для работы с конкретной сущностью (например загрузка в бд сущностей которые получаем из файла). В контроллере обычно минимум логики, вся логика в сервисах

Comment: Почитать бы по подробнее про это, как писать этот сервис. И все таки нужен репозиторий или нет?

Comment: Читайте книгу «шаблоны корпоративных приложений», автор мартин фаулер. Она не про веб вообще, но обьясняет, что архитектура выбирается под задачу, а универсальной архитектуры нет.

Comment: Смотрите [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/) и примеры [приложений](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture)

Comment: Посмотрел некоторые статьи и материалы на эту тему. Обьясните почему пишут что бы некоторые контроллеры запрашивали данные через сервис, который использует репозиторий, а некоторые сразу через репозиторий? В чем тогда смысл "сервиса" и "репозитория"?

Comment: Грубо говоря, репозиторий просто берёт данные из БД. А сервис данные как-то обрабатывает.

Comment: Опять же смотрел доклад о том что Repository и UoW, это анти-паттерны и так уже не имеет смысла делать.